# Conditional Numpy shuffling

Tags: python, numpy, random, shuffle

**Problem**
Assume you have a structured `np.array` as such:

```
first_array = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9])
```

and you would like to create a new `np.array` of same size, but shuffled.

E.g.

```
second_array = np.random.shuffle(first_array)

second_array 
# np.array([3, 2, 9, 5, 6, 1, 1, 6, 9, 7, 8, 5, 2, 7, 8, 3, 4, 4])
```

So far, so good. However, random shuffling leads to some duplicates being very close to each other, which is something I'm trying to avoid.

**Question**
How do I shuffle this array so that the integer order is pseudo-random but so that each duplicate has high probability to be very distant to each other? Is there a more specific term for this problem?

Comment: I remember that this was a common problem when shuffling music playlists; users complained that "the shuffle is not good enough" because there would often be two consecutive titles from a same artist. As a result, Spotify and pretty much every playlist software are now using "smoothed" shuffle algorithms that are not uniformly random, and avoid adjacent similar titles.

Comment: Yeah I also remember Spotify had that problem. Good hint, thanks.

Comment: Similar problems: [Function to make a list as unsorted as possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70508442/function-to-make-a-list-as-unsorted-as-possible/70510656);  [A Stack Overflow user's curious problem of maximising unsortedness](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/7501/a-stack-overflow-users-curious-problem-of-maximising-unsortedness);

Comment: [Randomising a list whilst ensuring duplicates are not sequential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797136/randomising-a-list-whilst-ensuring-duplicates-are-not-sequential); [Disperse Duplicates in an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17899312/disperse-duplicates-in-an-array); [An algorithm that spreads similar items across a list](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/262557/an-algorithm-that-spreads-similar-items-across-a-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of an algorithmic problem than `numpy` only. A naive approach can be to split the array with the minimum target spacing (`spacing_condition`), that numbers should be at least that far apart.

```py
import numpy as np
first_array = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9])
spacing_condition = 3
subarrays = np.split(first_array, spacing_condition)
```

Next step is to choose sequentially from `subarrays` in order, this would guarantee the `spacing condition`, and remove the choice from that subarray along.

However, this last two step, naive loops will be slow for large arrays. Following a naive implementation, seed is there only to reproduce.

```py
np.random.seed(42)

def choose_over_spacing(subarrays):
    choices = []
    new_subarrays_ = []
    subarray_indices = np.arange(len(subarrays[0]))
    for subarray in subarrays:
        index_to_choose = np.random.choice(subarray_indices, 1)[0]
        number_choice = subarray[index_to_choose]
        choices.append(number_choice)
        new_subarray = np.delete(subarray, index_to_choose)
        new_subarrays_.append(new_subarray)
    return choices, new_subarrays_

all_choices = []
for _ in np.arange(len(subarrays[0])):
    choices, subarrays =  choose_over_spacing(subarrays)
    all_choices = all_choices + choices
```

Inspecting the resulting, we see that we guarantee that duplicated numbers are at least 3 numbers apart, as we condition with `spacing_condition`, one could choose different spacing condition as long as initial split works.

```py
[2, 6, 8, 3, 6, 7, 2, 5, 9, 3, 4, 9, 1, 4, 8, 1, 5, 7]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. I was thinking about solving it similarily and this method works great. I am now trying to figure out how to do the same but with 2D arrays. I stupidly forgot to mention that this is my goal.

Comment: @Novorodnas For 2D, you would need to define spacing condition in the other dimension too, similarly.

Comment: I'll use the euclidean distance to do that.. thanks a lot!